# Spring cloud Stream - kafka - Null Acknowledgement Header

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I want to manually Commit the offset using spring cloud stream - only when the message  processing is successful.
Here is my code - application.yml & Handler Class

```
      public void process(Message<?> message) {
         System.out.println(message.getPayload());
         Acknowledgment acknowledgment = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
        if (acknowledgment != null) {
           System.out.println("Acknowledgment provided");
           acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        }
    }
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
spring:
  application:
      name: springCloud
  cloud:
      stream:
          default-binder: kafka
          kafka:
              bindings:
                  myChannel:
                      consumer:
                          autoCommitOffset: false
```

But my Acknowledgement object is null as in the header object 'kafka_acknowledgement' itself is NOT present.

1. How to get the acknowledgment object?
2. My requirement is to commit the offset ONLY if the processing is successful, if the processing fails  I do NOT want to pop the message from the channel so that it can be read later.
   Will the above code be sufficient to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version are you using?

In 3.1, `autoCommitOffset` was deprecated in favor of setting the `ackMode` (to `manual` in this case); however, it looks like `autoCommitOffset` is now completely ignored rather than deprecated.

Comment: I am using 3.1.0 . How to set ackMode in application properties? what is the property name?

Comment: `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input-in-0.consumer.ack-mode=manual` or `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input-in-0.consumer.ack-mode=manual-immediate` (or `...ackMode` refer to the spring-amqp documentation for the difference).

Answer (score 0):

When using yaml file, please use the property 'auto-commit-offset'.